# Ensuring a parent class' constructor is called only for the first instance, in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am working on a model where I will have one parent class, named `database`. This will have the methods which will directly work on the database. I will have a few other classes which will extend the `database` class in order to use its functionality (access the database). However, these classes need to have their own `__construct` method defined, and the `database` class will connect to the database in its `__construct` method.

An example of what I mean is below, the `__construct` of the `user` class explicitly calls a query (which will only work if the `__construct` method of the `database` class has been invoked).

```
<?php
    class database {
        private $mysqli;

        function __construct() {
            $this -> mysqli = new mysqli(..login_details..);
        }

        public function query($query) {
            return $this -> mysqli -> query($query);
        }

    }

    class user extends database {

        function __construct() {
            $users = $this -> query("SELECT * FROM users");
            while($u = $users -> fetch_assoc()) {
                print_r($u);
            }
        }

    }

    $user = new user();

?>
```

One way around it is to explicitly call `parent :: __constructor();` in the subclass, but I do not want it to have to re-connect to the database for each inherited class, i.e I only want it to connect the first time a class inherits it. How would I go about doing this? Would I have to do this outside of the `database` construct?:

```
private static $mysqli = new mysqli(...);
```

Or am I going about implementing my model the completely wrong way?

Comment: Minor code guideline suggestions: class names should have an initial capital letter, they should be contained within their own file, and all methods should have an access level (so the constructors should be explicitly `public`). These things are not necessary, but they're good to have - they're part of the PSR guidelines.

Comment: I think you're trying to do too much in the constructor. From a testing perspective, you want to be able to instantiate a class without it doing anything - I'd think about moving the database logic into a separate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say go with dependency injection instead of inheritance. Think about the `is a` relationship inheritance usually implies. For instance a class `cat` may inherit from class `mammal`. This makes sense as a cat `is a` mammal.

This really doesn't make sense in your case. Maybe pass in a database object in the constructor when you instantiate the user class.

```
class user{
         private $DB = null;

        function __construct(database $DB) {
            $this->DB = $DB;
            $users = $this -> DB -> query("SELECT * FROM users");
            while($u = $users -> fetch_assoc()) {
                print_r($u);
            }
        }

    }
$DB = new database();
$user = new user($DB);
```

There is more than one way to get the result you want, I just think this is a more appropriate approach. Also you can use the original `database` object without calling the constructor multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was my initial design and I was trying to opt for a more OOP approach, but I guess there's not much point.